# ldd: cannot find library for xl c compiled binary but could for gcc compiled binary on AIX

Tags: aix, libraries, dynamic-linking

I have compile on AIX two version of proftpd one with `gcc` and one with the `xl c compiler` from IBM.
The command line to compile both version are almost the excat same, but when I do a `ldd` on the `gcc` version, I have no problem while when I try to `ldd` the xl compiled I have for the `libmysqlclient.a` the message :
`Cannot find libmysqlclient.a(libmysqlclient.so.16)`
though I do include the library correct path during the compilation.
So the question is how can I identify the path where the binary look for binary or how can I include this path during compilation ?

Feel free to ask for further details, I'll update my question.

**Edit 1** ldd result:
for the gcc version I have :

```
ldd/usr/local/proftpd/sbin/proftpd
/usr/local/proftpd/sbin/proftpd needs:
    /usr/lib//libc.a(shr.o)
    /opt/freeware/lib/libcrypto.a(libcrypto.so.1.0.1)
    /usr/lib//libpam.a(shr.o)
    /opt/freeware/lib/libssl.a(libssl.so.1.0.1)
    /opt/freeware/lib/mysql/mysql//libmysqlclient.a(libmysqlclient.so.16)
    /opt/freeware/lib/libz.a(libz.so.1)
    /unix
    /usr/lib//libcrypt.a(shr.o)
    /usr/lib//libc.a(shr_64.o)
    /usr/lib//libpthreads.a(shr_xpg5_64.o)
    /usr/lib//libmls.a(shr.o)
    /opt/freeware/lib/libgcc_s.a(shr.o)
    /usr/lib//libpthread.a(shr_xpg5.o)
    /usr/lib//libcrypt.a(shr_64.o)
    /usr/lib//libpthreads.a(shr_xpg5.o)
    /usr/lib//libmlsenc.a(shr.o)
    /usr/lib//libodm.a(shr.o)
    /usr/lib//libpthreads.a(shr_comm.o)
```

For the xl C version I have :

```
ldd proftpd-1.3.4d/proftpd
proftpd-1.3.4d/proftpd needs:
    /usr/lib/libc.a(shr.o)
    /opt/freeware/lib/libcrypto.a(libcrypto.so.1.0.1)
    /usr/lib/libpam.a(shr.o)
    /opt/freeware/lib/libssl.a(libssl.so.1.0.1)
    Cannot find libmysqlclient.a(libmysqlclient.so.16)
    /opt/freeware/lib/libz.a(libz.so.1)
    /unix
    /usr/lib/libcrypt.a(shr.o)
    /usr/lib/libc.a(shr_64.o)
    /usr/lib/libpthreads.a(shr_xpg5_64.o)
    /usr/lib/libmls.a(shr.o)
    /usr/lib/libcrypt.a(shr_64.o)
    /usr/lib/libpthreads.a(shr_xpg5.o)
    /usr/lib/libmlsenc.a(shr.o)
    /usr/lib/libodm.a(shr.o)
    /usr/lib/libpthreads.a(shr_comm.o)
```

**Edit 2+1** compilation command (with a bit a formatting to make it more readable:
To compile with XL C I use this script

```
export CONFIG_SHELL=/opt/freeware/bin/bash
export CONFIG_ENV_ARGS=/opt/freeware/bin/bash
export CC=cc
export CFLAGS="-qmaxmem=16384 -DSYSV -D_AIX -D_AIX32 -D_AIX41 -D_AIX43 -D_AIX51 -D_AIX52 -D_AIX53 -D_AIX61 -D_ALL_SOURCE -DFUNCPROTO=15 -O -I/opt/freeware/include"export CXX=xlC
export CXXFLAGS=$CFLAGS
export F77=xlf
export FFLAGS="-qmaxmem=16384 -O -I/opt/freeware/include"
export LD=ld
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/freeware/lib64 -L/opt/freeware/lib:/opt/freeware/lib/mysql/mysql -Wl,-blibpath:/opt/freeware/lib64:/opt/freeware/lib:/usr/lib:/lib -Wl,-bmaxdata:0x80000000"
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/etc:/usr/sbin:/usr/ucb:/usr/bin/X11:/sbin:/usr/vac/bin:/usr/vacpp/bin:/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/dt/bin:/usr/opt/perl5/bin:/opt/freeware/bin:/opt/freeware/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/lib/instl
make clean
./configure 
    --with-modules=mod_tls:mod_sql:mod_sql_mysql:mod_sql_passwd:mod_sftp:mod_sftp_sql 
    --without-getopt 
    --enable-openssl 
    --with-includes=/home/user/include3_mysql/zlib:/home/user/include_mysql/mysql:/opt/freeware/lib/mysql/mysql 
    #with or without it doesn't work
     --with-libraries=/opt/freeware/lib/mysql/mysql  
     --prefix=/local/proftpd
make
```

The command line from GCC is a bit longer but without all the export part :

```
make clean
./configure 
    --with-modules=mod_tls:mod_sql:mod_sql_mysql:mod_sql_passwd:mod_sftp:mod_sftp_sql 
    --without-getopt 
    --enable-openssl 
    --with-includes=/opt/freeware/include:/opt/freeware/include/mysql/mysql/:/home/user/libmath_header/ 
    --with-libraries=/usr/lib/libc.a:/opt/freeware/lib/libcrypto.a:/usr/lib/libpam.a:/opt/freeware/lib/libssl.a:/opt/freeware/lib/mysql/mysql//libmysqlclient.a:/opt/freeware/lib/libz.a:/unix:/usr/lib/libcrypt.a:/usr/lib/libc.a:/usr/lib/libpthreads.a:/usr/lib/libmls.a:/opt/freeware/lib/libgcc_s.a:/usr/lib/libpthread.a:/usr/lib/libcrypt.a:/usr/lib/libpthreads.a:/usr/lib/libmlsenc.a:/usr/lib/libodm.a:/usr/lib/libpthreads.a 
    --prefix=/home/user/proftpd_bin
make
```

**Edit 4**:
Does anybody have any small clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally use this script to allow the compilation:

```
export CONFIG_SHELL=/opt/freeware/bin/bash
export CONFIG_ENV_ARGS=/opt/freeware/bin/bash
export CC=cc
export CFLAGS="-qmaxmem=16384 -DSYSV -D_AIX -D_AIX32 -D_AIX41 -D_AIX43 -D_AIX51 -D_AIX52 -D_AIX53 -D_AIX61 -D_ALL_SOURCE -DFUNCPROTO=15 -O -I/opt/freeware/include"export CXX=xlC
export CXXFLAGS=$CFLAGS
export F77=xlf
export FFLAGS="-qmaxmem=16384 -O -I/opt/freeware/include"
export LD=ld

export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/freeware/lib64 -L/opt/freeware/lib -Wl,-blibpath:/opt/freeware/lib64:/opt/freeware/lib:/usr/lib:/lib:/opt/freeware/lib/mysql/mysql -Wl,-bmaxdata:0x80000000"

export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/etc:/usr/sbin:/usr/ucb:/usr/bin/X11:/sbin:/usr/vac/bin:/usr/vacpp/bin:/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/dt/bin:/usr/opt/perl5/bin:/opt/freeware/bin:/opt/freeware/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/lib/instl
make clean
./configure 
--with-modules=mod_tls:mod_sql:mod_sql_mysql:mod_sql_passwd:mod_sftp:mod_sftp_sql 
--without-getopt 
--enable-openssl 
--with-includes=/home/padubois/include3_mysql/zlib/:/home/padubois/include_mysql/mysql/ 
--with-libraries=/opt/freeware/lib/mysql/mysql:/opt/freeware/lib/mysql/mysql/libmysqlclient.a 
--prefix=/local/proftpd/
make
```

I was misusing `LDFLAG` here's the important part :
`-blibpath:/opt/freeware/lib64:/opt/freeware/lib:/usr/lib:/lib:/opt/freeware/lib/mysql/mysql`

Happy new year

Comment: Nice that you found it! Happy new year to yourself too!

Comment: *"I was misusing LDFLAG..."* - Do you show the good or bad `LDFLAGS`? If it is the good one, how is it different from the old one?

Comment: it's been a very long time since i did this, but I had not used the correct mysql lib missing: `/opt/freeware/lib/mysql/mysql` @jww

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 2** I see another line that's weird:

```
--with-includes=[...]/opt/freeware/lib/mysql/mysql
```

Shouldn't that be `/opt/freeware/include/mysql/mysql` instead?

Also you haven't added `/opt/freeware/lib/mysql/mysql` to LDFLAGS when compiling.

**Edit** I see one thing that might explain it:

```
/opt/freeware/lib/mysql/mysql//libmysqlclient.a(libmysqlclient.so.16)
```

Note the extra `/` in there. I'm by no means an expert in xl, but it might possibly be getting confused by that, if you used the same notation when compiling in both compilers.

(Original answer: From my vague memory of AIX, I believe you want to add the path to the environment variable `LIBPATH`. )

Comment: well problem is it's empty if it's the correct name :D

Comment: It would probably help if you showed what the command line options you used were. I'm by no means an expert in the xl c compiler, but it would appear obvious that it didn't link things in the same way as gcc did.

Comment: well I will as soon as I manage to get my bash history file back -.-'

Comment: Changed my answer based on your edit

Comment: Well now it's not compiling anymore, so Is it a bug or feature ? I 'll update the question.

Comment: That was a nice try but not the good one, removing the trailing `/` from build line did not make the trick.

Comment: I can't think of anything else. But if you add the build command line to the question, somebody else might have a clue.

Comment: I added the buiild lines if you have an idea

Comment: considering this `--with-includes=[...]/opt/freeware/lib/mysql/mysql ` it was an attempt with or without do not change anything, I already include the header. I'll try to set the `LDFLAGS but I though ``configure` script would do that

Comment: `LDFLAGS` is set in export script. But now I really run out of idea about what to include or not

Comment: thank you for the support I finally find a solution according to your advice so I upvote you.